# Dictionary updateValue causes swift compiler segmentation fault

Tags: swift, xcode6

My class has a property

```
var activeSquares = Dictionary <String, SKShapeNode> ()
```

I try to add and update values in the dictionary using

```
let squareNode = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(80, 80), cornerRadius: 8)
activeSquares.updateValue(squareNode, forKey: "someUniqueDescription")
```

I also get the same crash if I use

```
activeSquares["someUniqueDescription"] = squareNode
```

But it is causing a crash when compiling

```
1.  While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC14gamename9GameScene11addedSquarefS0_FCS_6SquareT_ for 'addedSquare' at /.../gamename/gamename/GameScene.swift:30:5
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

How do I properly use updateValue to add/update key/value pairs to my dictionary?

Comment: first thing I'd try is updating to Xcode6 Beta 3 (since the compiler should not segfault)

Answer (score 0):

No sure if my solution fits here, but it could help. Seems there's something weird with subscription for NSDictionary. Not sure why, but it's defined as:

```
func objectForKeyedSubscript(key: NSCopying!) -> AnyObject!
```

so, if I'm not wrong it returns implicitly unwrapped optional, but should return optional, as far as there could be no value for a key. If you try to write:

```
if(dictionary["key"] != nil)
```

you'll get a compile error "AnyObject is not convertible to UInt8" while if you write:

```
if(dictionary["key"])
```

you don't get one.

The way I solved this issue was using optional unwrapping, so:

```
if(someBool && dictionary["key"]) // fine in beta 2, crash in beta 3-4

// turned to:

var hasValueForKey = false
if dictionary["key"]
{
    hasValueForKey = true
}
if(someBool && hasValueForKey) // fine in beta 4
```

and:

```
var someArray : NSArray? = dictionary["key"]? as? NSArray // note ? after []
```

I guess there could be something with optionals and stuff for setting an object via subscript, it's defined as:

```
    func setObject(obj: AnyObject!, forKeyedSubscript key: NSCopying!)
```

Maybe playing with optional unwrapping could help here as well.